# Loadrunner encode difference between Record and Replay

Tags: loadrunner

different encode value between LoadRunner Record and Replay, how to make the same encode? any method or settings in LoadRunner? it caused the request fail due to ";" symbol.

[image]

Comment: Which step did you use? Maybe you need to add a header with the correct encoding to your HTTP request (http://lrhelp.saas.hpe.com/en/12.53/help/function_reference/Content/web/lrFr_web_add_header.htm)?

Comment: And on a different note. From the looks of your screenshot that value is generated by the server and should be different between record and replay. But it is hard to tell from just this one snapshot.

Comment: the header is the same, I'll update snapshot for header info; and yes, it's different value between record and replay, my point is in recode, it's '/', but in replay, it's ';', it seems they're different encoding;

Comment: What is this string? Maybe its a viewstate or something which will be different each time

Comment: you can see the string from attached picture, the characters under blue background.

Comment: I meant, what is the meaning of this string within the response? If this is a string generated by the server then it may be different each time. Try to replay several times and see if the string is different each time.

Comment: got it, i'll do that, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried HTML to PLAIN conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Have you asked the developer about the encoding model used?